# How to use a SymPy.core.add.Add as a value for a math calculation inside a Python function

Tags: python, function, sympy

I have a function that I loop through with a array of values. Then I integrate it twice and I need
to use the value of this second integration inside another function.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy 
from sympy.abc import a, x, y

#First function
def m1(x):
    mn = (-110 + 210*x + -113*x**2 + 141*x**3 + -869*x**4 + 2980*x**5 +
          -6150*x**6 + 7848*x**7 + -6079*x**8 + 2626*x**9 + -485*x**10)
    return mn

#Array of values 
dist = np.arange(0, 1.09, 0.01)
result_m1 = [] #Empty list to store results

#Iteration over array
for v in dist:
    result_m1.append(m1(v))

f1 = sympy.integrate(m1(x), x) #First symbolic integration
f2 = sympy.integrate(f1, x) #second symbolic integration

def d(x):
    df = (-1)*(f2)/(67e9*4.72537401e-9)
    return df

#Second iteration for another batch of results
result_d = []
for v in dist:
    result_d.append(d(v))
```

Whenever I run the code above, I get that result_m1 is a list of numbers (usable) and result_d is a list of expressions/SymPy symbols equations (unusable).
I need f2 to be a symbolic equation so I'll end up with a function like the m1 function (One that I can iterate with the array).

Comment: Your description of the results is not clear.  It might help if you showed some results, not just talked about them (otherwise we'd have to run your code ourselves - ugg :)  ).  Is `dist` the only use of `numpy`?  Using `sympy` and `numpy` together often results in problems, though tat might not be the case here.

Comment: I've run your code, and see the problem (but not the solution - yet).  I think you can construct a simpler example.  While `x` is an argument of your `m1` function, and `m1(y)` or `m1(0)` shows that, `d` is not the same kind of function.  `df` does not depend on the `x` argument

Comment: try using `symlp.lambdify`

Comment: @hpaulj, sorry about not showing some results, it was a list repeating the mn expression 109 times, so I wouldn't be pretty to show here. But I get what you said about the difference in the x's, the answer below did it for me! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a confusion between the global sympy variable `x` and the parameter `x` to the functions. These are not the same. It's best to give them separate names to decrease the confusions. Then, you'll note that `f2` uses the symbol `x`. This can be replaced with the parameter value via `f2.subs(x, xi)`:

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy
from sympy.abc import a, x, y

#First function
def m1(xi):
    mn = (-110 + 210*xi + -113*xi**2 + 141*xi**3 + -869*xi**4 + 2980*xi**5 +
          -6150*xi**6 + 7848*xi**7 + -6079*xi**8 + 2626*xi**9 + -485*xi**10)
    return mn

#Array of values
dist = np.arange(0, 1.09, 0.01)
result_m1 = [] #Empty list to store results

#Iteration over array
for v in dist:
    result_m1.append(m1(v))

f1 = sympy.integrate(m1(x), x) #First symbolic integration
f2 = sympy.integrate(f1, x) #second symbolic integration

def d(xi):
    df = (-1)*(f2.subs(x, xi))/(67e9*4.72537401e-9)
    return df

#Second iteration for another batch of results
result_d = []
for v in dist:
    result_d.append(d(v))
```

As noted in the comments, `lambdify()` can be used to create a numpy version that allows to write the calls benefiting numpy's [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy
from sympy.abc import a, x, y

#First function
def m1(xi):
    mn = (-110 + 210*xi + -113*xi**2 + 141*xi**3 + -869*xi**4 + 2980*xi**5 +
          -6150*xi**6 + 7848*xi**7 + -6079*xi**8 + 2626*xi**9 + -485*xi**10)
    return mn

dist = np.arange(0, 1.09, 0.01)
m1_np = sympy.lambdify(x, m1(x))  # use lambdify to create a numpy version of function m1
result_m1 = m1_np(dist)

f1 = sympy.integrate(m1(x), x) #First symbolic integration
f2 = sympy.integrate(f1, x) #second symbolic integration

def d(xi):
    df = (-1)*(f2.subs(x, xi))/(67e9*4.72537401e-9)
    return df

d_np = sympy.lambdify(x, d(x))
result_d = d_np(dist)
```